With FlixBus, do I have to get on at the exact stop my ticket specifies if there are multiple stops in the same city?
Yesterday I was travelling on a FlixBus departing from Göteborg/Gothenburg, in which most if not all FlixBus services make stops both at Nils Ericson Terminalen and Korsvägen. I had booked a ticket that would have me picked up at Korsvägen, but due to last-minute planning changes it would've been more convenient to hop on at Nils Ericson Terminalen.
Reading For the FlixCompanies: General Terms and Conditions of Carriage, it says "2.2 The booking confirmation (see clause 3.1) entitles the passenger to a journey between the start and destination indicated on the ticket. A later boarding or earlier disembarkation is not permitted due to legal regulations". However, it isn't clear to me if "start and destination" refer to the city or exact stop.

Looking at the ticket, I could both read it as that the start and destination are Göteborg and Linköping, as well as Korsvägen and Linköping Fjärrbussterminal. As such, I wonder, do I have to get on the exact stop as noted on my ticket if there are other ones in the same city?

"due to legal regulations" most likely means "due to us wanting to squeeze more money out of the customer" :-)

@Hilmar At my city we have public intra-city bus and public regional bus. Regional buses are not allowed to carry people between stops inside the city; as my city is a terminal for almost all of the lines there are stops where an incoming bus will allow you to leave the bus but not to get in, and and outgoing bus will allow you to get in but no to leave the bus (because that would mean that the transport had been only inside the city).

@Hilmar Similar in my area: There's a transport association, and all operators that sell tickets for trips within the covered area, have to enter the association, sell tickets at the given price etc. Flixbus doesn't want to do this, so they chose to only sell tickets entering or leaving (or transiting through) the associations area, but no tickets within the area.

Officially you can't. And most likely the driver won't let you do that. Once I got away shortening a connection and taking an earlier bus, but the driver's machine was defective and he only looked at my ticket briefly. All the other times I needed to wait for my original time of departure.
You can also get away boarding on a different station on Flixtrain, since they only check you once you are inside, and not immediately when boarding like on Flixbus.
